# Parse json and convert it to php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to echo a value from google map json url. I can var_dump() the keys and the values but I can't pull the specific value alone. Php code:

```
<?php
    $from = 'Piccadilly+Circus+London+UK';
    $to = 'Brighton+Railway+Station+Brighton+UK';
    $json ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='.$from.'&destinations='.$to.'&mode=driving&key=APIKEY';
    $ch = curl_init($json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Print Result
    echo '<pre>' . var_dump($data) . '</pre>';

?>
```

The var_dump() result is as follows;

```
       string(542) "{
       "destination_addresses" : [ "Brighton, Queens Rd, Brighton BN1 3XP, UK" ],
       "origin_addresses" : [ "Piccadilly Circus, London W1B, UK" ],
       "rows" : [
          {
             "elements" : [
                {
                   "distance" : {
                      "text" : "86.7 km",
                      "value" : 86665
                   },
                   "duration" : {
                      "text" : "1 hour 59 mins",
                      "value" : 7114
                   },
                   "status" : "OK"
                }
             ]
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }
    "
```

I need to assign **distance->text** to a php variable. Could anyone help?

Comment: You need to use `json_decode` to make that an array.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$variable = json_decode($data)->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert the json to a php array variable you can use `json_decode($data, true)` with the second parameter to true, to convert it to an associative array.

code example.

```
$json = json_decode($date,true);

print  $jsonp['rows'][0]['elements']['0']['distance']['value'];
```

Doc. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Hope it helps.